# exponential distribution probability(exponential time inteval)

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

Can someone guide me how to solve this question,i want to familiar with the exponential distribution theory.

[image]

for part (a) I think "there are no calls within a 30 min. interval" = "getting a call after 30 min"

so if X = time between calls.

for part(a) answer is value of  P(X<30)

Is my thinking correct?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Could you put the picture into the question?

Comment: I haven't enough reputation for post pic. on the question.

Comment: I've uploaded it. Plus usually showing some of your own thoughts towards the question will make more people to look into the problem and help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for part (a) I think "there are no calls within a 30 min. interval" = "getting a call after 30 min"

Not quite. No calls within a 30 minute interval includes cases where you get a call after 31 min, 32 min, etc.

Let's say at $t=0$, you receive a call and then $X = $ the time until you receive the second call. It should be clear that this is just a restatement of the problem, one that I hope will be easier for you to wrap your head around.

So for part a), you want $P(X>30)$.

Can you use my restatement to answer the remaining parts?

Comment: Thank you very much and I think for part (b) P(X<10) and part (c) P(5<X<10)

Comment: Yep, that's correct.